# nested process substitution followed by pipe: "bad file descriptor"

Tags: zsh

I've run into a perplexing error that I'd like to understand better.  The problem seems to require the presence of a "wrapper" shell function (as described below), so my immediate interest is to find out how to modify such a shell function to get rid of the error.  (I give a more specific statement of my question at the end of the post.)

The simplest code that I've come up with to reproduce this error is given in the following script.  (This script is certainly artificial and silly, but the real-life situation in which the error first surfaced is a bit too complicated for a demonstration like this one.)

```
# create an input file
cat <<EOF > demo.txt
a
b
c
EOF

# create a "wrapper shell function" for /usr/bin/join
my_join_fn () {
  /usr/bin/join "$@"
}
cat <(my_join_fn  <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt))
cat <(my_join_fn  <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt)) | head -1

# create a "wrapper shell function" for /usr/local/bin/gjoin, a port of
# GNU's join function for OS X
my_gjoin_fn () {
  /usr/local/bin/gjoin "$@"
}
cat <(my_gjoin_fn <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt))
cat <(my_gjoin_fn <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt)) | head -1

# show the version of zsh
$SHELL --version
```

If one sources this script (under `zsh`), it terminates successfully, and produces the following (correct) output:

```
% source demo.sh
a
b
c
a
a
b
c
a
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2)
```

But if one then re-executes *directly from the command line* either one of the two lines in the script that end with `| head -1`, one gets a `bad file descriptor` error:

```
% cat <(my_join_fn  <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt)) | head -1
join: /dev/fd/11: Bad file descriptor
% cat <(my_gjoin_fn <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt)) | head -1
/usr/local/bin/gjoin: /dev/fd/11: Bad file descriptor
```

*These are the only two lines in the script that produce an error when run directly on the command line.*

As indicated in the output of `$SHELL --version`, the results shown above were obtained under OS X, but I get similar results when I perform an analogous test under Linux:

```
% cat <(my_join_fn  <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt)) | head -1
/usr/bin/join: /proc/self/fd/11: No such file or directory
% $SHELL --version
zsh 4.3.10 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

---

I have not been able to reproduce this error under `bash` (OS X or Linux).  This leads me to suspect that the error is due to a bug in `zsh`.  But, if so, it is an extremely arcane bug, and thus not likely to be fixed any time soon.

Therefore, I'd like to find a workaround.  My question is:

> How should I modify the definition of the wrapper shell function `my_gjoin_fn` so as to avoid this error?

(The real-life counterpart for `my_gjoin_fn` is almost identical to the one given above, differing only in the inclusion of a flag in the invocation of `gjoin`:

```
my_gjoin_fn () {
  /usr/local/bin/gjoin -t$'\t' "$@"
}
```

I use this wrapper shell function *all the time*, therefore I'd really like to "salvage" it.)

EDIT:

The error persists even if I replace the `| head -1` at the end of the command with `| head -10`, `| cat`, `| tee /dev/null`, `| :`, etc.  E.g.:

```
% cat <(my_join_fn  <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt)) | cat
/usr/bin/join: /proc/self/fd/11: No such file or directory
```

Also, adding `ls -l /proc/self/fd`, as suggested by msw, produces the following:

```
% cat <(ls -l /proc/self/fd; my_join_fn  <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt)) | cat
total 0
lrwx------ 1 jones jones 64 Aug 21 12:29 0 -> /dev/pts/18
l-wx------ 1 jones jones 64 Aug 21 12:29 1 -> pipe:[312539706]
lrwx------ 1 jones jones 64 Aug 21 12:29 2 -> /dev/pts/18
lr-x------ 1 jones jones 64 Aug 21 12:29 3 -> /proc/23849/fd
/usr/bin/join: /proc/self/fd/11: No such file or directory
```

...which doesn't tell *me* much, but may be more informative to others.  FWIW, the output produced by the `ls -l /proc/self/fd` subcommand looks the same whether I run this under `zsh` or under `bash`.  Also, FWIW, the output of `ls -l /proc/self/fd` when run by itself is

```
% ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 jones jones 64 Aug 21 12:32 0 -> /dev/pts/18
lrwx------ 1 jones jones 64 Aug 21 12:32 1 -> /dev/pts/18
lrwx------ 1 jones jones 64 Aug 21 12:32 2 -> /dev/pts/18
lr-x------ 1 jones jones 64 Aug 21 12:32 3 -> /proc/5246/fd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behaviour using `zsh 4.3.10 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`.

```
% cat <(funjoin  <(cat demo) <(cat demo)) | head -1 
join: /proc/self/fd/11: No such file or directory
```

I dug into the manual and the closest I found to this problem was the chapter Process Substitution in `man zshexpn` and MULTIOS in `man zshmisc`.

Both chapters are suggesting a workaround involving putting curly braces around part of the command.

I tried that

```
% { cat <(funjoin  <(cat demo) <(cat demo)) } | head -1
1
```

and it works.

I was not able to fully grok what the semantics of `{ }` is in zsh. The manual explains it simply as a list of commands. I also do not fully understand what exactly this MULTIOS does. It seemed to make no difference whether it was enabled or disabled.

I tried to place the curly braces in different places, including in the body of the function `funjoin`, but the only place where it works correctly is around the outer `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this under zsh_5.0.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb on Linux but `/proc/self/fd/11` seems like a pretty high number. Does it only fail with `head -1`? How about `head -10`? Does the output of

```
cat <(ls -l /proc/self/fd ; my_join_fn  <(cat demo.txt) <(cat demo.txt)) | head -1
```

yield any illumination?

Comment: Thanks, I've added information to my post that addresses your questions.